# How to construct JPA entites and JSON models?

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa, model

My spring application consuming JSON API then saves it in database using JPA. I'm facing problem with properly designed entites and models.

My model JSON looks like:

```
@Data
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TvShowRemote implements TvShowEntity {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public Integer id;
    @JsonProperty("url")
    public String url;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;
    @JsonProperty("summary")
    public String summary;
    @JsonProperty("updated")
    public Integer updated;
    @JsonProperty("_embedded")
    public Embedded embedded;

    public List<SeasonEntity> getSeasons() {
        return new ArrayList<SeasonEntity>(embedded.getSeasons());
    }

    public List<EpisodeEntity> getEpisodes() {
        return new ArrayList<EpisodeEntity>(embedded.getEpisodes());
    }
}
```

My JPA entites looks like:

```
@Data
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
@Entity
@Table(name = "TvShows")
public class TvShowLocal implements TvShowEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Integer id;

    public Integer tvShowId;

    public String name;

    public Integer runtime;

    public String summary;

    @Column(name = "seasons")
    @OneToMany
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = SeasonLocal.class)
    public List<SeasonLocal> seasons;

    @Column(name = "episodes")
    @OneToMany
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = EpisodeLocal.class)
    public List<EpisodeLocal> episodes;

    @Override
    public List<SeasonEntity> getSeasons() {
        return new ArrayList<SeasonEntity>(seasons);
    }

    @Override
    public List<EpisodeEntity> getEpisodes() {
        return new ArrayList<EpisodeEntity>(episodes);
    }
}
```

Lombok annotation @Data automatically implements getter/setters. 
I tried to implement to both classes interface:

```
public interface TvShowEntity {

    Integer getId();

    String getName();

    List getSeasons();

    List getEpisodes();
}
```

There's also two interface SeasonEntity, EpisodeEntity which I implemented in SeasonRemote, SeasonLocal, EpisodeRemote, EpisodeLocal. They looks like in example above.

Now I trying to assign TvShowRemote to TvShowLocal;

```
TvShowEntity tvshowEntity = new TvShowRemote();
TvShowLocal tvShowLocal = (TvShowLocal) tvShowEntity;
```

But I cannot cast this object like this.
Is there better way to achieve this?

Comment: For starters, `@JsonProperty` is redundant if you're not changing the property name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TvShowEntity tvshowEntity = new TvShowRemote();
TvShowLocal tvShowLocal = (TvShowLocal) tvShowEntity;
```

You're trying to achieve an **impossible** cast which can't be done.

`TvShowRemote` is a `TvShowEntity`

and

`TvShowLocal` is a `TvShowEntity`

It doesn't mean that `TvShowRemote` is a `TvShowLocal` and vice versa.

**You can use the Adapter design pattern.**

Comment: Thank you for answer. I know that cast can't be done. That's why I asked It possible to achieve this in better(proper) way. How can I create my model classes that I Can assign TvShowRemote -> TvShowLocal easily?

Comment: use the adapter design pattern, or just do your cast manually by coding

Comment: Thank you! I will use adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I see that both TvShowEntity and TvShowLocal extends TvShowEntity.
But you can't cast a TvShowEntity that was instantiated as a TvShowRemote to a TvShowLocal.

From [Wideskills](http://www.wideskills.com/java-tutorial/java-object-typecasting):

> The cast can be to its own class type or to one of its subclass or    superclass types or interfaces.

You should copy properties from TvShowRemote to TvShowLocal manually or just use the supertype TvShowEntity if you declare all needed method interfaces.